# E2029 '(' expected but 'THEN' found

Tags: if-statement, delphi, syntax, syntax-error, pascal

So I'm trying to write a function in Delphi 10.4 that takes a JSON file out of a SQL table and shows all the items within on a grid.

One of those is in a date format which causes the app to crash, so naturally I try figuring out which it is so I can format it correctly.

However, the method I used to try and find it keep showing the above error:

```
procedure InjectJSONIntoTable(Query: TFDQuery; MemTable: TFDMemTable; Edit: TEdit);
    var
        jsonString: string;
        jsonArr: TJSONArray;
        jsonItem: TJSONObject;
        jsonValue: TJSONValue;
        i: Integer;
        j: Integer;
        dummyString: string;
    begin
        // applies the sql command
        Query.SQL.Text := Edit.Text;
        Query.Open;
        // transforms the sql return back into JSON
        jsonString := Query.FieldByName('jdoc').AsString;
        jsonArr := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonString) as TJSONArray;
        // preps the table to receive the data
        MemTable.Close;
        MemTable.CreateDataSet;
        MemTable.Open;
        MemTable.Insert;
        // appends the data to the table;
        for i := 0 to jsonArr.Count -1 do begin
          jsonItem := jsonArr.Items[i] as TJSonObject;
          for j := 0 to MemTable.Fields.Count - 1 do begin
            MemTable.Edit;
            jsonValue := jsonItem.GetValue(MemTable.FieldDefs[j].Name);
            if jsonValue.ClassType = TDateTime then ShowMessage('tralala');
                                                               ^ '(' expected but 'THEN' found
            MemTable.Fields[j].AsString
              := jsonItem.GetValue(MemTable.FieldDefs[j].Name).Value;
          end;
        end;


        MemTable.Post;
        // shows data on the table
    end;
```

And perhaps I'm blind but I honestly can't figure out where the error is coming from.

I've tried a bunch of stuff, switching the order of the elements around, but the error either persists of a bunch of new errors show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TJSONValue.ClassType()` method returns a `TClass`, which can only point to `TObject`-derived types.  `TDateTime` is not a class derived from `TObject`, so you can't use `ClassType = TDateTime` (or `ClassType is TDateTime`, like [@Dúthomhas suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76167308/65863)).

JSON has no concept of date/time values, so there is no `TJSON...` class implemented for `TDateTime`.  A date/time would just be a `string` to JSON.

As [@JPRitchey mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76167362/65863), you can use the [`TJSONValue.TryGetValue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.TryGetValue) method to *convert* the value of `jsonValue` into a `TDateTime`, checking if that conversion succeeds or fails. Just note that `TryGetValue<TDateTime>()` will succeed *ONLY IF* either:

- `jsonValue` is a `TJSONString` object, and the string value is expressed in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (as the conversion uses [`DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate)).
- `jsonValue` is a `TJSONBool` object. The conversion will set the `TDateTime` to `1.0` (December 31 1899) or `0.0` (December 30 1899), depending on the boolean value.

Otherwise, `TryGetValue<TDateTime>()` will return `False`.

If that does not suit your needs, you will have to check the JSON value yourself manually, eg:

```
var dtValue: TDateTime;

jsonValue := jsonItem.GetValue(MemTable.FieldDefs[j].Name);

// use whatever makes sense for your particular use-case...
if TryStrToDateTime(jsonValue.Value, dtValue) then
  ShowMessage('tralala');

MemTable.Fields[j].AsString := jsonValue.Value;
```

Comment: Took some fiddling but this worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

TDateTime is not a class.  It's basically an alias for the Double type.

The error is because the only thing that makes sense right there is to do a typecast such as *TDateTime(someVariable)*.

I believe what you want to do is something like

```
var LDateTimeVar: TDateTime;
if jsonValue.TryGetValue<TDateTime>(LDateTimeVar) then ShowMessage('tralala');
```